# Qt attempting to include openCV library files

Tags: qt, opencv

Am I correctly including all the library files from the directory ??

`LIBS += "C:\openCV24\opencv_bin\lib\*.dll"`

Because this line keeps on giving me

`C:\openCV24\opencv_bin\install\lib*.dll: Invalid argument`

Ive tried looking several places and have altered this line many times but cant seem to get it to work. Can someone please let me know if Im missing a step ??

I have alreay included the includepath and that work fine `INCLUDEPATH += "C:\openCV24\opencv_bin\install\include"` but its the additional library files that throw an error

Thx alot really getting annoyed

Answer (score 1):

Libs option in pro file not for Dll files, it is for lib files. Try LIBS += "C:\openCV24\opencv_bin\lib\*.lib". Also "*.lib" usage may cause problems because of link order.

**update**
here is my pro file template for OPENCV. Also you should add opencv bin folder to your path.

```
#begin{opencv}
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\opencv\opencv\build\include"
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\opencv\opencv\build\include\opencv"

LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_calib3d231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_contrib231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_core231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_features2d231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_flann231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_gpu231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_haartraining_engine.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_highgui231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_imgproc231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_legacy231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_ml231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_objdetect231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_ts231.lib
LIBS += C:\opencv\opencv\build\x86\vc9\lib\opencv_video231.lib
#end{opencv}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still same error....I dont understand why its not working because I followed a tutorial and it seemed to work fine for him ??
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgcXYQijV6c&feature=related
would be great if I could get this too work, cant start my project because of this issue

Comment: In the video, they are using a directory called bin: LIBS +=  "C:\openCV24\opencv_bin\bin\\*.lib" not LIBS +=  "C:\openCV24\opencv_bin\lib\\*.lib" as the library include path. Does that make any difference for you?

Comment: again thx for trying...but no still same problem, in the video they use "\*.dll" and this would make sense considering there is dll files in bin folder.

Also I found another tutorial which includes the libraries slightly differently http://www.barbato.us/2011/03/18/using-opencv2-within-qtcreator-in-windows-2/ 
Btw are lib files meant to have .lib extensions because there none in mine, just dll and .a ??

Comment: Maybe I should re-install ?? but how would I remove all the outputs of the makefiles, just a plain delete ??

Comment: I'm using QT+Opencv without problem. In your pro file, define libs(not dlls, libs), define includes and put your dlls into a path where your executable can find them. (I'm updating my answer with sample pro file)

Comment: @bmeric thx that second set of library files done it for me...but I didnt include your two other files I just did my original bin INCLUDEPATH += "C:\openCV24\opencv_bin\install\include"

Thanks alot really appreciate it